# AWS CLI CodeArtifact : What value to supply for --package flag for list-package-versions subcommand

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, aws-cli, aws-codeartifact

## Problem Statement

I am trying to see what versions have been deployed for a specific Maven package in AWS CodeArtifact.  I do not have the ability to view anything through the web GUI so I am using the AWS  CLI.

When I run the following command `aws codeartifact list-packages --domain kickingtires --repository kickingtires` the output looks as follows

> PACKAGES        maven   edu.excelsior.api       core

So basically there is one Maven artifact in the *kickingtires* repository : `edu.excelsior.api:core`.  I have deployed two versions of this artifact and want to list the versions using the AWS CLI.

I have tried to run the following permutations

```
aws codeartifact list-package-versions --domain kickingtires --repository kickingtires --format maven --package edu.excelsior.api

aws codeartifact list-package-versions --domain kickingtires --repository kickingtires --format maven --package edu.excelsior.api.core

aws codeartifact list-package-versions --domain kickingtires --repository kickingtires --format maven --package edu.excelsior.api:core

aws codeartifact list-package-versions --domain kickingtires --repository kickingtires --format maven --package "edu.excelsior.api"

aws codeartifact list-package-versions --domain kickingtires --repository kickingtires --format maven --package "edu.excelsior.api.core"

aws codeartifact list-package-versions --domain kickingtires --repository kickingtires --format maven --package "edu.excelsior.api:core"
```

However the response is always as follows

> An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the ListPackageVersions operation: The maven package '$PACKAGE' does not exist in repository 'kickingtires

## Question

What is the appropriate value of the --package parameter for the list-package-versions subcommand to retrieve the Maven artifact versions?  I have checked the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codeartifact/list-package-versions.html) but it doesn't have a meaningful answer to this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be too late to be helpful to the original poster, but I just ran into this problem and hopefully my answer will help someone else. In order to target a package that has a namespace (groupId in maven speak), you need to include both `--package` (just the package name/artifactId) and `--namespace` (the groupId) to the line. You cannot target both with just `--package`, at least I couldn't find out how, and you can't look for just the package name without the namespace, it will claim not to find it.

So I believe something like this should work:

```
aws codeartifact list-package-versions --domain kickingtires --repository kickingtires --format maven --namespace edu.excelsior.api --package core
```

Hope this help someone some day.

Comment: This was extremely helpful. By the time you posted it I had taken a new job, then old job called back and needed assistance with this. Why does this not appear in AWS documentation. SO should let us tag companies. Anyway ty